# graphql and relational databases avoiding complex SQL queries

Tags: postgresql, performance, subquery, relational-database, graphql

I have inherited a Graphql based API. Whilst it is very neat looking code, the database (Postgres) and the SQL queries that fetch the actual data are some of the most convoluted I have seen. I can't do much caching, as the data is real-time. I am finding it difficult to find ways of breaking these complex SQL queries (which paralyse the DB) into smaller manageable ones (multiple joins, sub-queries etc).

With a Rest architecture, whilst the code was not nearly as neat, I could design small simple queries called many times, which is much more scalable from an Infrastructure standpoint.

Have others experienced the same issues, and how have you solved this ?